# Can we set a field that gets computed by another field automatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say we have this schema

```
{
  "rating": 0,
  "reviews": [
    {"name": "bob", rating: 5},
    {"name": "ann", rating: 3}
  ]
}
```

How can we compute the rating field when the reviews array gets updated ?

Edit: using Node & mongoose

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest, You can simply use python "pymongo" library to update the field of rating after performing some calculations on the record present in the review array. Maintain a cron job for this function that updates the record every hour or every day.

Comment: https://hcoelho.com/blog/22/Prototyping_a_calculated_field_on_MongoDB_for_quick_access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up doing is adding 2 functions.

One for adding a review and inside of that function we can call methods that we define on that schema

```
productSchema.statics.addReview = async function (_id, review) {
  const doc = await this.findById(_id);
  doc.reviews.unshift(review);
  doc.calculateRating(); <-- now we can call calculateRating() only when addReview function gets called

  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(doc.save()));
};

// methods on the schema lets us call the function on the doc itself
// note that es6 arrow functions wont work in this case because
// arrow functions explicitly prevent binding this
productSchema.methods.calculateRating = function () {
  const total = this.reviews.reduce((sum, reviewObj) => sum + reviewObj.rating, 0);
  this.rating = (total / this.reviews.length).toFixed(2);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a [pre save hook](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre) on your schema to auto-update the rating on every save:

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  let totalRatings = this.reviews.reduce((total, review) => total + review.rating);
  this.rating = totalRatings / this.reviews.length;
  next();
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to check what field gets updated ? I dont want to compute it on every update just when the array gets updated

Comment: @AsafAviv you can check the `modifiedpaths` in the hook before recalculating. See the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-modifiedPaths). But if you're worried about the performance of a simple array reduce, you may want to change the format of your reviews so that each is saved as a single document. You want to avoid documents which [keep growing in size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-operations/#document-growth-and-mmapv1)